# How to change the text color and background color of ant-tooltip component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I implemented antd tooltip but need to change the background color and text color of it but I am unable to achieve that. I tried to do using "overlayStyle" provided by antd tooltip component but no luck not working as expected. As Shown below.

```
<Tooltip
    title={jobNumber * 3}
    placement="bottomRight"
    overlayStyle={{
        color: "orange",
        background: "blue",
    }}
>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `${jobNumber * 3}px` }} />
</Tooltip>;
```

I tried inspecting it but unable to do so as its work on hover and till the time I move my cursor to class but no help.

What I founded on hover the div added one class named 'ant-tooltip-open' but what's that in the class I can't see.

Comment: Can you please add a jsfiddle for this, so that I can inspect...

Comment: the example you can see from this link https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this easily, see below code

```
.ant-tooltip-inner {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: green;
}

.ant-tooltip-placement-bottom .ant-tooltip-arrow, .ant-tooltip-placement-bottomLeft .ant-tooltip-arrow, .ant-tooltip-placement-bottomRight .ant-tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

here is working demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVvyGr

[image]

Comment: that triangle is also getting that light color, you can see it by changing background color of your body to dark color, it may not be visible properly because there is no shadow to it like tooltip, even if you tried to add shadow to triangle it will look as square so better use different color

Comment: It does not work for the arrow but using :
.ant-tooltip-arrow::before {
  background-color: white;
}
It fixes the arrow color

Comment: Also add !important to color and backgroundColor to make sure it works.

Comment: May I change className of the tooltip hint? (not the tooltip button / text / div)
This is necessary in case I want to have different styles on different tooltips...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can useful for you.
In order to change the color of the ant tooltip arrow use:

```
.ant-tooltip-arrow::before{
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the color of the arrow **use this**:

```
.ant-tooltip-arrow-content{
    background-color: #fafafa !important;
}
```

because it stays as black even when changing the background color of the tooltip and apparently this line of code **didn't work for me in Chrome**:

```
.ant-tooltip-placement-bottom .ant-tooltip-arrow, .ant-tooltip-placement-bottomLeft .ant-tooltip-arrow, .ant-tooltip-placement-bottomRight .ant-tooltip-arrow {
        border-bottom-color: green;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For somebody's looking for a theme setting solution, the color of a tooltip could be set on a theme with `colorTextLightSolid` token